# Unclear formula in the book of linear model for classification in the Bishop book (machine learning)

Tags: machine-learning

From [Bishop's](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/%7Ewurmd/Livros/school/Bishop%20-%20Pattern%20Recognition%20And%20Machine%20Learning%20-%20Springer%20%202006.pdf) book pag 183 - (4.11) (Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning, 2009), a mathematical relationship is immediately shown without an explanation of where it is derived from:

[image]

[image]

I cannot understand where 4.11 comes from and the meaning of the lambda parameter prensent in the formula

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have two vectors (points in $\mathbb{R}^n$) called $x$ and $y$. Now, any point on the line between $x$ and $y$ is of the form $x + t(y-x).$ This is because the formula I just wrote is saying that "you start from $x$, then move $t$ units along the vector $y-x$," where $y-x$ is the line passing through $y$ and $x$. Then notice that $$x + t(y-x) = x(1-t) + yt,$$ which is the expression in the above.

Comment: Thanks. Please, do you have a proof to understand where the formula is derived from?

Comment: Is the equation above not enough of a "proof"? The formula follows sort of by definition I think.